# After writing a node stream length is zero

Tags: c#, xml

I am writing a xml node in the memorystream using xmlwriter.writenode(reader,false) under the parent element node named "root" ,for some of the nodes the stream length is always zero.My code will be look like this,

```
MemoryStream ms=new MemoryStream();

xmlTextWriter writer= new XmlTextWriter( ms, encoding );

writer.WriteStartElement( "root" );

writer.WriteNode( reader, false );

if(ms.length!=0)
{
.....
....
}

writer.WriteEndElement();

writer.Flush();
```

i can get the length where i flush the writer after i wrote the node.Is there any optimization for a length of the stream regarding small sized or large sized node?

Comment: The `XmlWriter` won't flush to the underlying stream after writing a node unless you explicitly tell it to.  But you've worked that out.  So what are you asking? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi..thanks for ur reply..My question is that the length is zero even i wrote some nodes,but for some nodes (large data) length is not zero,before flushing it ..what the reason for it??

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`XmlTextWriter` uses a `StreamWriter` internally which has a default buffer size of 1Kb.

As your write your XML, the contents will be written using this `StreamWriter`, and this will only flush its buffer to the underlying `Stream` once it is full or when `Flush()` is called.

Writing a small node may not fill this buffer, whereas writing a large node may do.  This is why, with large nodes, you are seeing data is flushed to the `MemoryStream` before you explicitly call `Flush()`.